# ¿Cómo puedo utilizar una variable declarada dentro de una funcion, fuera de ella?

Tags: python, python-3.x, poo, funciones, variables

soy uno mas de tantos, nuevo en Python (3.7) y en POO, he empezado de cero hace poco y voy avanzando como puedo, por eso estoy aquí hoy.
Mi pregunta me ha surgido al intentar sacar el valor de una variable, fuera de la función en la que ha sido definida, para asignársela  a otra variable que esta fuera.

Ejemplo:

```
cuenta = 100

def calculo():
    saldo = int()
    global cuenta
    while saldo < cuenta:
        total = cuenta-1
        cuenta = total

        #print(saldo)
        print(cuenta)

calculo()
```

Lo que necesito es actualizar el valor de la variable cuenta que esta fuera de la función, con el valor resultante de total.

En el ejemplo, anterior, donde pone: "cuenta = total" esto, no me actualiza la variable fuera.

¿Existe alguna forma de poder actualizar ese valor?

Llevo poco con Python y por mas que he buscado opciones no encuentro forma de hacerlo.
Gracias por vuestra ayuda.

Comment: ¿Por que dices que no te actualiza la variable `cuenta`? lo que veo es que justamente al finalizar la función `calculo()` si revisas esta variable, el valor será `0`, es decir, está justamente modificando el valor de esta variable.

Comment: Es cierto, la verdad es que ese fragmento lo hice de cero y después me di cuenta de que ahí si funcionaba.
En cambio en el código completo no.
El problema es que en la función de calculo, me da un error de atributos, el objeto str no tiene atributo get. La variable dentro de la función que recibe el valor de cuenta desde un Entry fuera de la función, utiliza un get para ello y el error mencionado ocurre al entrar por segunda vez en la función. Todavía estoy atascado y no se como resolverlo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error no es por querer modificar la variable global, sino por que estás intentado convertir un objeto `Entry` a `int`.
lo que debes hacer esto en el `__init__`:

```
global valor1
valor1 = StringVar(self.ventana)
cuenta1 = Entry(self.ventana, font=14, width=4, textvariable=valor1)
```

y en el `fcargar`:

```
global valor1
cuentaval = int(valor1.get())
```

Comment: Perfecto! Muchísimas muchísimas gracias!. Perfectamente explicado!. Da gusto ver tan buenos profesionales por aquí. Un montón de gracias!.

Comment: Podrías marcar la respuesta como correcta? por favor

Answer (score 0):

Voy a intentar aclarar un poco más mi consulta con una parte del código extraída del programa:

```
from tkinter import *

class App:
    def __init__(self):
        global cuenta1
        cuenta1 = int()
        self.ventana = Tk()
        self.ventana.geometry("500x300+500+100")
        self.ventana.title("APP")
        self.ventana.configure(bg='gray51')
        self.lblcuenta1 = Label(self.ventana, bg='gray51', font=14, text="CUENTA: ")
        self.lblcuenta1.place(x=50, y=120)
        cuenta1 = Entry(self.ventana, font=14, width=4)
        cuenta1.place(x=150, y=120)
        self.cargar = Button(self.ventana, text="CARGAR", bg="gray71", font=14, width=10, height=1, command=self.fcargar)
        self.cargar.place(x=250, y=115)

        self.ventana.mainloop()

    def fcargar(self):
        global cuenta1
        cuentaval = int(cuenta1)
        total = cuentaval - 1
        cuenta1 = total
        print("Obtiene valor del Entry ", cuentaval)
        print("total ", total)
        print("cuenta1 ", cuenta1)


def main():
    mi_app = App()
    return 0


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Y a continuación el error que me da Python:

```
line 22, in fcargar
    cuentaval = int(cuenta1)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Entry'
```

Por tanto la consulta es:
Porque me da ese error?, no alcanzo a entenderlo.
Cómo puedo actualizar la variable cuenta1 que esta fuera de la función, con el valor "total" calculado en la función?
Gracias por ayudarme!.

Comment: No crees una respuesta para aclarar la pregunta, edita la pregunta y añade esta información.